# I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS installed, how do I upgrade to 12.10 using a DVD?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS as the sole operating system and would like to upgrade to 12.10.  I have burned the ISO image to a DVD.  How do I go about upgrading via WiFi or using the DVD?

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay upgrading over the internet via WiFi then you should be able to just go to the software updater and upgrade! If you cannot see an upgrade option you may need to go into settings and change "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "For any new version".

To upgrading using a DVD, just boot into the DVD and there should be an option to upgrade the current installation.

Before you upgrade you may want to check that your hardware can run Unity 3D as Unity 2D isn't included in 12.10 and you will be forced to use Unity 3D which would run unbearably slowly! Plus, you would probably want to back up all your data just in case anything goes wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already burned iso into DVD use DVD itself. It is the better way to upgrade from DVD. But you have to make sure that you have created bootable DVD. And don't forget to have a backup of all your data(documents).